# How can I show "$" instead of "US$" in NSnumberFormatter?

Tags: ios, swift, currency, nsnumberformatter, chinese-locale

I used below code for conversion from NSnumber to currency with locale.

```
let price = 12.34 as NSNumber
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.currencyCode = "USD"
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "zh_CN") as Locale
print(formatter.string(from: price)!)
```

> Expected Output: $12.34 ,
> Actual Output: US$12.34

Could you please help me to resolve this behaviour.

Comment: Set `formatter.currencySymbol` ? – You did browse https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter for a possible solution, didn't you?

Comment: Try `let amountString = String(format: "$%.02f", amount)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a currency symbol other than the default for the currency code and Locale, you can manually specify that using the `currencySymbol` property of `NumberFormatter`.

```
let price = 12.34
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.currencyCode = "USD"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "zh_CN")
formatter.currencySymbol = "$"
print(formatter.string(for: price) ?? "nil") // "$12.34"
```

Other improvements to your code: don't use `NSLocale` in Swift, use `Locale` instead, especially when you cast the `NSLocale` to `Locale` immediately. You don't need to convert numbers to `NSNumber` just to format them either, you simply need to call `NumberFormatter.string(for:)` instead of `string(from:)` when using numeric types other than `NSNumber`.